# LayoutManager for different sized components without coding absolute positions

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm trying to create some UI but no idea how to use `LayoutManger` for it.

[image]

Like showing in the image Purple color component have fixed width and height but stick to the corners. 8 and 4 have fixed with and variable height, 2 and 6 have fixed height and variable width. the middle component (9) need variable width and height.

These 8 component work like a border and middle one is need to resize according to parent component size. I could do this coding absolute positions using null layout. but I have suggested to not to use null layout.

How could I do this with a Layout manager witch layout I can use for this? Do I need to use more layouts than one?

**UPDATE**

i have tried something with `GridBagLayout` as Andrew's suggestion but I still need a little help to understand how it works. Here is my code

```
 import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridLayoutTest {
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        jPanel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        
        
        
        JButton button;

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        button = new JButton("1");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        jPanel1.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("2");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        jPanel1.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("3");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        jPanel1.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("4");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        jPanel1.add(button, c);

        //Panel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.green.darker());
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        //c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        jPanel1.add(panel, c);

        button = new JButton("5");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        jPanel1.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("6");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        jPanel1.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("7");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        jPanel1.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("8");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        jPanel1.add(button, c);
        
        
        frame.add(jPanel1);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }
   
}
```

[image]

Comment: That could be achieved using a `GridBagLayout` with appropriate constraints. Give it a go and get back to us with a [mre] if you get stuck.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I will try it. thanks

Comment: If you'd like to see a JPanel that looks like what you're proposing, I created a [Qlocktwo](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/qlocktwo) a while back.  The main JPanel is made up of 9 subordinate JPanels.

Comment: *Do I need to use more layouts than one?* - that is always an option when designing a form layout. However, I agree, that with this requirement a GridBagLayout should solve the problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson need a little help if you don't mind.

Comment: *"need a little help if you don't mind"* You've come to the right person re help on a [mre]. An MRE needs to include imports and a `main` method. Everything that it needs in order to compile cleanly and run to show the problem in our IDE.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have updated the code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the following GUI.

[image: GridBagLayout GUI]

I set all six of the GridBagConstraints (anchor, fill, gridx, gridy, weightx, weighty) for each element of the grid.  That way, I could more easily keep track of what the values were for each element.

Here's the complete runnable code I used.  In other words a minimal, reproducible example.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridBagLayoutGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GridBagLayoutGUI());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayout GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        JButton button;

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        button = new JButton("1");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        c.weightx = 0.0d;
        c.weighty = 0.0d;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("2");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.weightx = 1.0d;
        c.weighty = 0.0d;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("3");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;
        c.weightx = 0.0d;
        c.weighty = 0.0d;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("4");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        c.weightx = 0.0d;
        c.weighty = 1.0d;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(button, c);

        // Panel
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
        innerPanel.setBackground(Color.green.darker());
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.weightx = 1.0d;
        c.weighty = 1.0d;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(innerPanel, c);

        button = new JButton("5");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
        c.weightx = 0.0d;
        c.weighty = 1.0d;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("6");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
        c.weightx = 0.0d;
        c.weighty = 0.0d;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("7");

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.weightx = 1.0d;
        c.weighty = 0.0d;
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("8");
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
        c.weightx = 0.0d;
        c.weighty = 0.0d;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        panel.add(button, c);

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: The use of buttons gives it a nice look. Consider disabling the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be [JGoodies FormLayout](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/). I have been using this in combination with [JFormDesigner](https://www.formdev.com/) for all my layouting needs since basically forever. It covers 95% percent of my use cases. The remaining 5% is BorderLayout and absolute positioning (null layout).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A common strategy to solve complex computing tasks, is to break them into small, well defined manageable tasks. Divide and conquer.
This also applies to gui: you can break the design into small, easy to layout containers.
In this case the needed layout can be achieved by using `BoxLayout` and `BorderLayout`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.Box.Filler;
import javax.swing.*;


public class FramedContent extends JPanel{

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 35, CONTENT_SIZE = 300, BORDER_SIZE = 1;
    private static final Color CORNER_COLOR = Color.MAGENTA, RULLER_COLOR = Color.BLUE,
                                CONTENT_COLOR = Color.GREEN, BORDER_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    FramedContent(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(header(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(center(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(header(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private JPanel header(){
        JPanel hExpandPane = new JPanel();
        hExpandPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(hExpandPane, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        hExpandPane.add(corner());
        hExpandPane.add(hRuller());
        hExpandPane.add(corner());
        return hExpandPane;
    }

    private JComponent corner(){
        Dimension d = new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_WIDTH);
        Filler filler = new Filler(d, d, d);
        filler.setBackground(CORNER_COLOR);
        filler.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(BORDER_COLOR, BORDER_SIZE));
        filler.setOpaque(true);
        return filler;
    }

    private JComponent hRuller(){
        Dimension d = new Dimension(0,FRAME_WIDTH);
        Filler filler = new Filler(d, d, new Dimension(Short.MAX_VALUE, FRAME_WIDTH));
        filler.setBackground(RULLER_COLOR);;
        filler.setOpaque(true);
        return filler;
    }

    private JPanel center(){
        JPanel vExpandPane = new JPanel();
        vExpandPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        vExpandPane.add(vRuller(), BorderLayout.WEST);
        vExpandPane.add(content(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        vExpandPane.add(vRuller(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        return vExpandPane;
    }

    private JComponent vRuller(){
        Dimension d = new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, 0);
        Filler filler = new Filler(d, d, new Dimension(FRAME_WIDTH, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        filler.setBackground(RULLER_COLOR);
        filler.setOpaque(true);
        return filler;
    }

    private JPanel content(){
        JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());// GridBagLayout used just to center the content
        content.setBackground(CONTENT_COLOR);
        content.add(new JLabel("Your Content Goes Here"));
        content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CONTENT_SIZE,CONTENT_SIZE));
        return content;
    }

    public static void createWindow()   {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Framed content");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(new FramedContent());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createWindow();
    }
}
```

---

[image]